# How to override UpgradeSchema.php file in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have override following code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.7', '<')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
                'company',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                     'nullable' => false,
                      '255',
                    'comment' => 'Company Name'
                ]
            );
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
                'address',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                     'nullable' => false,
                      '255',
                    'comment' => 'Address'
                ]
            );
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
                'city',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                     'nullable' => false,
                      '255',
                    'comment' => 'City'
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

but its not working?

Comment: What is your module.xml setup_version?

Comment: module.xml                                                                                                                                     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>

Comment: di.xml                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Customer\Setup\UpgradeSchema" type="Vendor\Module\Setup\UpgradeSchema" />
</config>

Comment: Have you module InstallSchema.php file or not?

Comment: no only upgradeschema

Comment: You need to write first InstallSchema.php.

Comment: ok wait i have check it

Comment: i have write installschema.php file but its not override upgradeschema.php file

Comment: can i manuallly add column in customer_entity table